# Selenium Limitation

Tags: selenium, automation

While running selenium automation, some cases are failing because of slowness,some cases because of some other cases failed already (for example if selenium clicks an link , and that link shows the list of documents, from that document listing ,if selenium do some action, if the initial link is failed to load the document listing means, the whole case is failed , if many cases depends on the initial link means all the cases are failed, but those failed cases works well if selenium perform the same action from clicking on different link and getting document listing ), Any ideas to over come this problem

Comment: Test cases should **absolutely not** be dependant on each other, which it sounds like they are. What 'slowness'? Have you observed the test run? Where is it slow? When it clicks the button? Actually finding the elements? The page load? What driver are you using? Show us some basic working code that is slow, and **measure** how slow it is. Are you using explicit waits? If not, why not? Implement them!

Comment: @Arran Unit tests may not depend on another, but this is not true for GUI tests. As long as an application produces and holds state, the succession of your tests will influence the outcome. GUI tests should mock the customer's journey in the first place. Isolation from each other can only be second priority then.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is not Selenium limitations but just common chalenges of test automation that you will have to face.

About Slowness that make test cases fail. You basically have 2 strategies to make your test cases to pass. First one is to slow down the speed of execution of your test case (there are commands in Selenium lib for that). That's not great as your test suite will end up very long. Second way is to use "wait until element is present" technique. With that function, you can wait until a button is visible on the screen before asking selenium to click on it.

About test cases that depend one on the other. Here what you want to do is to break big and/or interdependent test cases into small and independent test cases. For example you could have TC1 that test that when clicking on a link it displays a list of document. If you want to do some action on that documents list in TC2, then you should find a way for TC2 to set its initial configuration without Selenium. For some web page it is going to be a specific/custom URL that can drive the display of some elements. For some other it might be a cookie. You have to discuss with your dev team.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary defines, limitation as, "a condition of limited ability; a defect or failing", which none of your statements describe, relating to Selenium.

What comes to mind, is poorly designed tests cases -- for example, test case dependency, there having a single point of failure within all tests.
And slowness, again, if the designed is poor, why would anyone think test cases will perform realistically fast?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have designed all the test cases carefully with using best page locators for the application. There are some simple things that may help you to reduce the number of failures.

Example:

- Clear cache memory before starting execution.
- Try to clear cookies if cookies are not required  for the rest of the
  execution.
- Use of    wait(either explicit or implicit and even use of sleep).
- Check for    the selenium webdriver version and the browser version
  it supports    (Many times this may be the cause for failure).

These are some basic things that can help to reduce failures.

Answer (score 0):

**Limitations of Selenium**

1. Can’t handle windows pop-up.
2. Can’t automate mobile applications/windows applications.
3. Can’t automate captcha.
4. Less support is provided by selenium.
5. Must have hands-on on any one language which is supported by selenium.
6. No inbuilt report generation need to do with Junit, TestNg and Extentds Report.

Answer (score -1):

Text execution depends on performance of your application also.If its selenium,make sure you have included following code in your script,

```
package com.test;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Wait {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.id("gb_70")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
    }
}
```

Also if the application is slow in identifying a object.Then use WeDriver wait. It includes various options like "elementToBeClickable","elementToBeSelected","presenceOfElementLocated".

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gb_70")));       

element.click();

WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("Email")));  

element1.sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
```

Comment: This is horrific: `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`! Implicit waits apply whenever you try to locate an element. If that element exists, the call will return fast. But if you check for the absense of an element by intention ("I don't an error message to appear!") than your test will be blocked for 20 seconds! This will really slow down your tests and you might not even grasp where this comes from.